# Почему когда делают переход по URL с GET параметром, то в начало адреса добавляется приставка /public. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get, backend

Такая проблема. Есть кнопка на сайте, а к ней добавлен GET параметр. Когда я нажимаю перейти то осуществляется переход, но к адресу добавляется `/public`. Если убрать GET параметр и оставить ссылку, то все хорошо и ссылка стандартная.

Так выглядит ссылка на сайте

```
http://shop/admin/orders/change/2/?status=1
```

А так, когда начинает осуществляться переход по ней

```
http://shop/public/admin/orders/2/edit
```

Как убрать приставку public?

Comment: еще надо вернуть change и куда-то деть статус

Comment: Это все обрабатывается у меня. Проблема с добавлением начинается, именно до того, как он поступает в начальный контроллер. Я пробовал убирать всю логику в контроллере и сразу возвращать ответ. И с get параметром - он подставляет /public, а без - выводит как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, проблема была в том, что хостинг определял основную папку не public, а саму папку с проектом. Написал в тех поддержку, они исправили и потом вставил в htaccess такой код и перекинул его в папку public и все стало окей.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```